# Post on fb page using Drupal

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, drupal, drupal-7

Hello  am using drupal7 . i need to post my node on FB Fan Page.

Anybody have idea which module support this

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a module for that - http://drupal.org/project/fb